# How to stop local music of audioplayers plugin in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented local music for ringing call
so i used [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) plugin for that.
First i have located the music in asset folder in my project and defined the path in pubspec.yaml.
now unable to stop music on press of end call button.

piece of code:

```
const ringingAudioPath = "phone_ringing_sound.mp3";
AudioCache player = new AudioCache();

//On Calling:


 RawMaterialButton(
            
            onPressed: () async{
              //player.play(ringingAudioPath);
              player.loop(ringingAudioPath);
            } ,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.call,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 35.0,
            ),
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            elevation: 2.0,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          ),

//call end or cancel

 RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: () async{
              // player.clear(ringingAudioPath);
              
            } ,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.call_end,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 35.0,
            ),
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            elevation: 2.0,
            fillColor: Colors.redAccent,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          ),
```

Answer (score 2):

`AudioCache.clear` only clears the file from cache, simply use await on `loop()` to get the instance and by using this, you can call `stop()`.

**A simple example would be**

```
var ringingAudioPath = "images/ok_scan.mp3";
AudioCache playerCache = new AudioCache(); // you already initialized this

AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();   // now initialize player to stop the audio with player

void _playAudio() async {
  player = await playerCache.loop(ringingAudioPath); // asign your player here
}

void _stopAudio() {
  player?.stop(); // and now u can stop it like
}
```

Comment: some more control can be
        player.pause();    
    player.stop();    
    player.resume();

Comment: Not working ,Music still not stopping, keep rigning.

Comment: @ShrutiRamnandanSharma if this helps you can you mark it as answer?